# "Type synonym instances are disallowed" even though I have a newtype monad transformer

Tags: typeclass, monad-transformers, purescript, newtype, type-synonyms

I have defined a monad transformer `UlffT` as follows.

I'm working with `Halogen`, but this is not a `Halogen`-question - I'm just providing context. `UlffT` is meant to be stacked on `Aff` and used in `HalogenM`.

```
newtype UlffT m a = UlffT ( ExceptT Error (ReaderT Env m) a )

unUlffT :: forall m. UlffT m ~> ExceptT Error (ReaderT Env m)
unUlffT (UlffT m) = m

derive newtype instance functorUlffT :: Functor m => Functor (UlffT m)
derive newtype instance applyUlffT :: Monad m => Apply (UlffT m)
derive newtype instance applicativeUlffT :: Monad m => Applicative (UlffT m)
derive newtype instance bindUlffT :: Monad m => Bind (UlffT m)
derive newtype instance monadUlffT :: Monad m => Monad (UlffT m)

instance monadTransUlffT
      :: MonadTrans UlffT where
  lift = UlffT <<< lift <<< lift

instance monadEffUlffT
      :: MonadEff eff m
      => MonadEff eff (UlffT m) where
  liftEff = lift <<< liftEff

instance monadAffUlffT
      :: MonadAff eff m
      => MonadAff eff (UlffT m) where
  liftAff = lift <<< liftAff
```

Everything is fine up to here. Now I define the obvious instance for `MonadAsk` as follows.

```
instance monadAskUlffT
      :: MonadAsk Env (UlffT m) where
  ask = UlffT $ lift ask
```

And I get the error

```
Type class instances for type synonyms are disallowed.
```

`UlffT` is not a type synonym. I was expecting errors regarding `m`, e.g. I have to declare constraints like `Monad m => ...`, or `Monad (UlffT m) => ...`.

I get the same error, when deriving the `MonadAsk`-instance.

Comment: What is the `Env` type involved here? Perhaps that's the synonym?

Comment: That's the right answer

Answer (score 1):

gb's comment: of course `MonadAsk` has two params, the first one `Env` was the offender.